# How can I make a QTextEdit widget scroll from my program

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTextEdit widget with a vertical scroll bar.

```
report_text = new QTextEdit();
report_text->setAcceptRichText(true);
report_text->setReadOnly(true);
report_text->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
report_text->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
report_text->setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::NoWrap);
report_text->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);
report_text->setMinimumSize(600, 380);
report_text->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

This is Qt 4.8 embedded.

Now I need a method or an event I can send to the widget to make it it scroll up or down just as if the up or down buttons on the scroll bar had been pressed.

I tried the scroll() method, but I scrolls the whole widget, including the scroll bar.

I also tried sending a QWheelEvent, but nothing happens.

```
QWheelEvent ev(QPoint(), 10, 0, 0);
report_text->setFocus();
QApplication::sendEvent(report_text, &ev);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what about [setValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) ?

Comment: One more thing you are missing: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I found as a suitable solution:

The vertical scrollbar may be accessed using the `QTextEdit::verticalScrollBar()` method.

Scrollbars have a [`triggerAction()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#triggerAction) method to conveniently simulate user interaction with the buttons and the slider. The available actions are defined in [`QAbstractSlider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#SliderAction-enum).

So the resulting code is only a single line:

```
report_text->verticalScrollBar()->triggerAction(QAbstractSlider::SliderSingleStepAdd);
```

Interestingly, this works even when the scrollbar is hidden with

```
report_text->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Comment: great that you found a less hacky alternative. I am also working on UI simulation\automation right now :), so I may need this earlier than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

It is probable that the delta you provided is just way too small.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html#delta) of `QWheelEvent::delta()`:

> Returns the distance that the wheel is rotated, in eighths of a
>   degree. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forwards
>   away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was
>   rotated backwards toward the user.
>
> Most mouse types work in steps of 15 degrees, in which case the delta
>   value is a multiple of 120; i.e., 120 units * 1/8 = 15 degrees.

The text scrolling in Qt unit is the number of whole line. So if the widget computes that you want to scroll `0.9` lines, he might do nothing.

So try again with

```
QWheelEvent ev(QPoint(), 120, 0, 0);
```

Note: Nothing here apply to an event with control or shift modifier.